# How to inserting json stringify object into database with php mysqli

Tags: javascript, json, mysqli

hi guy's i need you help. 
i try to create a function for inserting data from json stringify object into mysql database use php mysqli.

the json stringify data got from this code

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#submit-file").click(function(){
            var myfile = $("#files")[0].files[0];
            var json = Papa.parse(myfile, 
                {
                skipEmptyLines: true,
                complete: function(results) {
    var serialize = JSON.stringify(results);
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "../php/tagihan/save_data.php",
       data: {array:serialize},
       cache: false,
       success: function(data) {
          console.log(data);
   
                }
            });
     }
        });

    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/PapaParse/4.3.5/papaparse.min.js"></script>
```

the data just view like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDMuR.png)

the the php code as far i try like this

```js
<?php
include("../../Connections/koneksi.php");

$array = json_decode( $_POST['array'] );

$p1 = $array;
foreach($p1 as $val)
{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO table(subject,message) VALUES('".$val['subject']."', '".$val['message']."')";
    $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
}
?>
```

Comment: Ok, and does it work? If not, do you get any errors? If so, what errors?

Comment: i got an error in the php code 
`foreach($p1 as $val)`

Comment: error massage like this `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\192.168.1.22\php\tagihan\simple_html_dom.php on line 6`

Comment: Is `$p1` a valid array containing the data? Also, you might want to build the query string before running it, instead of running it for every `foreach`

Comment: @DarrenSweeney im still not running it with my jquery code.
i just try the code with run the php file. and it give that eror

Comment: @RobSutan Just put `print_r($p1)` before foreach loop to know whether you are getting the data properly and in which format...

Comment: hmmm... i got wrong in my jquery.
because of that i cant pass the array

Comment: @YashParekh can you help me fixing my jquery?

Comment: @RobSutan Are you getting any console error??

Comment: yapz.. i got eror of that

Comment: Do as I told you above. Just out the `print_r($p1); exit;` before foreach and show what you get in console...

Comment: **Warning** your code is vulnerable to **SQL injection**. Please use parameterized queries.

Answer (score 1):

JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#submit-file").click(function(){
        var myfile = $("#files")[0].files[0];
        var json = Papa.parse(myfile, 
            {
            skipEmptyLines: true,
            complete: function(results) {
            var serialize = JSON.stringify(results);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "../php/tagihan/save_data.php",
                data: serialize,
                cache: false,
                success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
        }
    });

});
});
```

PHP:

```
<?php
include("../../Connections/koneksi.php");

$array = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

foreach($array as $val)
{
    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO table(subject,message) VALUES (?,?)')) {
        $stmt->bind_param("ss", $val['subject'], $val['message']);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: The issue with injecting the JSON string into an sql query is that part of the make up of a JSON string may include characters like ',' which will break the SQL query, which is why you need to encode the string.

Comment: @Krzysztof it give me an eror massage `<b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to a member function query() on a non-object in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\192.168.1.22\php\tagihan\save_data.php</b> on line <b>11</b><br />`
its on `$result = $mysqli->query($sql);`

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I thought sending and receiving JSON from frontend to backend is a problem.

Comment: T_T...
i want to send my data from that jquery on my database. 
i dont know the function for grab the array in php.
can you help me for this.. im stuck there and im very confuse now

Comment: @KrzysztofRaciniewski what is variable 'ss' in bind_param?

Comment: it's mind: - first parameter is string type - second parameter is string type php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php. Prepare statement is resistant to sql injection attacks.It should work, I didn't test this code, it's your work :)

Comment: and this for getting a file from an url ? `("php://input")` what url will be pass for that

Comment: php://input is a read-only stream that allows you to read raw data from the request body. In this case your stringify JSON